# Why does my code not read the 3 digit numbers from my txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is my code:

```
Top_5 = []
with open (("winscorefile.txt"),"r") as Top5_File:
    for number in Top5_File:
        Top_5.append(number)
        Top_5.sort()
        Top_5.reverse()
        number_of_items = len(Top_5)
     while number_of_items > 5:
        Top_5.pop()
        number_of_items = len(Top_5)

    for data in Top_5:
        print(data)
```

My text file looks like(it is a collection of scores and usernames):

```
62 rob 
100 rob
56 ROB 
54 rob 
76 bor 
64 bor 
52 a 
44 p1 
54 p1 
46 p2 
74 p1 
52 p2 
66 p2 
76 p2 
38 p2 
60 p1 
58 p1
```

My file is meant to output the top 5 highest scores. it is doing this but is only outputting the highest two digit numbers. I do not know why it ignoring the score of 100.

Comment: Your input is taken as strings, not numbers, therefore it's sorted lexicographically

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you, how do i change this?

Comment: You must `split` each line to the two data elements (number and text), then convert the number string to an `int` and put it together with the text to a tuple before sorting.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, i am struggling to adapt my code to this would you be able to send an example?

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you very mich for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the single lines on the space and convert the first part to an int.

Then you could add the number and the person as a tuple to your list:

```
Top_5 = []
Top5_File = """
    62 rob
    100 rob
    56 ROB
    54 rob
    76 bor
    64 bor
    52 a
    44 p1
    54 p1
    46 p2
    74 p1
    52 p2
    66 p2
    76 p2
    38 p2
    60 p1
    58 p1
""".strip().split("\n")
for number in Top5_File:
    number, person = number.strip().split(" ")
    Top_5.append((int(number), person))
# sort only once, outside the loop!
Top_5.sort(reverse=True)
number_of_items = len(Top_5)
while number_of_items > 5:
    Top_5.pop()
    number_of_items = len(Top_5)

for data in Top_5:
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
(100, 'rob')
(76, 'bor')
(76, 'p2')
(74, 'p1')
(66, 'p2')
```

---

If you don't want a tuple, you can use:

```
for number in Top5_File:
    Top_5.append(number.strip())
Top_5.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(" ")[0]), reverse=True)
number_of_items = len(Top_5)
while number_of_items > 5:
    Top_5.pop()
    number_of_items = len(Top_5)

for data in Top_5:
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
100 rob
76 bor
76 p2
74 p1
66 p2
```

Comment: i keep on getting this error how do i change this? number, txt = line.split(' ')   # txt is useless here
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>>

Comment: Sounds as if you have a line w/o a space, or an empty line somewhere in your file. Simple check if the line is empty/has no space and skip, or fix your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
Top_5 = []
with open (("winscorefile.txt"),"r") as Top5_File:
    for line in Top5_File:
        score, name = line.split(' ')
        Top_5.append(int(score))

Top_5.sort(reverse=True)
print(Top_5[:5])
```

Comment: most efficient way to do it, you just miss the names and scores should be sorted as number not as string to prevent lot of errors..

Answer (score 0):

You need to .read() or .readlines() after you open the file

```
Top_5 = []
with open (("winscorefile.txt"),"r") as Top5_File:
    for line in Top5_File.readlines():
        line = line.strip()    # remove white spaces
        number, txt = line.split(' ')   # txt is useless here
        Top_5.append(int(number))
    Top_5.sort()
    Top_5.reverse()
    for data in Top_5[:5]:   # this grabs the first 5 elements including 0,1,2,3,4 elements
        print(data)
```

edit*
if the input is: 76 p2, line.split(' ') should return an array of two objects (there is one space), so it looks like your data file has more than one space as a separator. try this:

```
for line in Top5_File.readlines():
    line = line.strip()    # remove white spaces
    if ' ' in line:        # check to make sure theres a space in there
        splitted = line.split(' ')
        number = splitted[0]
        Top_5.append(int(number))
```

Comment: i keep on getting this error how do i fix it? number, txt = line.split(' ')   # txt is useless here
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>>

Answer (score 0):

```
 for number in Top5_File:
        Top_5.append(number)
        Top_5.sort()
        Top_5.reverse()
        number_of_items = len(Top_5)
```

basically `number` is a row of your data, i.e. the first one would be `62 rob`

To extract this you would have to do something like this:

`number.split(" ")` which will split the row into an array containing: `["62", "rob"]` Then you have to parse the int which you could do with `arr[0] = int(arr[0]` Now your row will be in the form:

`arr = [62, "rob"]` now I would suggest adding the tuple of `(score, name)` to your Top_5 array like this:
`Top_5.append((arr[0], arr[1]))`

Then you will have to change your `sort and reverse` as you will be storing tuples and not just a string in the array Top_5. This can be done with the key parameter and a lambda I believe. It would look something like: 
`sort(key = lambda x: x[0])` and the same can be done for reverse.

I hope this helps!